# OpenID Connect possible with any Microsoft/Office365 account?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

I've been working on authentication and authorization within ASPNET Core.  I'm familiar with setting up OpenID Connect on my own Azure tenant (such as this [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)).

I'm also aware of how to register an client ID and secret on platforms such as Google (such as [this example](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/)).

But what's confusing to me is that is how to setup OpenID connect to allow for a user to sign in with their own Microsoft account, regardless of whether they're created their own account through https://signup.live.com/ or signing in from their own Office365 subscription.

Is this possible?  Or is OpenID Connect (for Microsoft) registrations only supported separately in each Azure AD tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register the Azure AD app, select **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**.

[image]

Keep `common` as the "TenantId" in your `appsettings.json` file, which will allow both AAD account/O365 account and personal Microsoft account to sign in.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try.